# Why is the result of my varible being output in terminal. Bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

main (){
    totalnumber
    totalfiles
}

totalnumber (){
    TNUM= ls -1 | wc -l
}

totalfiles (){
    FNUM= ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l
}

main
```

This is my script, whenever I run it however in a folder with 2 files and 2 it outputs 4 and 2 but I don't want these to be output in the terminal just yet. How can I stop this?

Comment: Variables are declared like this: `var=$(command)`. If you say `var= command`, this will try to execute the unexisting `var=` command with `command` as a parameter.

Comment: This is a similar/common problem in bash where whitespaces matter when assigning values to variables. Whitespaces matter in many places such as `[[..]]` etc in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not actually assigning the results with these

```
TNUM= ls -1 | wc -l
```

and

```
FNUM= ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l
```

Do:

```
TNUM=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
```

and

```
FNUM=$(ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l)
```

to assign the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

main (){
    totalnumber
    totalfiles
}

totalnumber (){
    TNUM=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
}

totalfiles (){
    FNUM=$(ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l)
}

main
```

if you would

```
echo $TNUM
echo $FNUM
```

after the call of `main`, you will see your output.